# Put search bar in foreground, above animated header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the Search Bar and Menu Button in the foreground. [wearethenewmedia.com/indextrial.html](http://wearethenewmedia.com/indextrial.html) This is a static page, with no CMS.

I tried using Z-index on everything and had no success.

In the above example, I haven simply put a negative margin on the search bar to put it in the top part of the website. It's hidden behind the solar system image, sticking out a bit.

Also, see original at [WeAreTheNewMedia.com](http://WeAreTheNewMedia.com). It's seriously too much code to post in here. (Multiple CSS and JS pages involved.)

Can someone use Firebug (Firefox plugin) and tinker around? We have tried adding "z-index" variables almost everywhere, throughout the CSS pages with no luck.

We're also trying to implement this sidebar with our Menu button. But have conflicting CSS and JS Link: wearethenewmedia.com/menu/index.html

Comment: I fixed the links.

Comment: If its too much code to post here, then its probably not a good fit for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically z-index does not work without defining the element's position, e.g.:

```
#sticky{
   ...
   z-index: 5; 
   position: absolute;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Margin is not the solution here, and `z-index`, doesn't have effect if there is no one of the positions set (relative, absolute, or fixed).

As I saw in the website, the solution could be adding position absolute to the header:

```
#sticky {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 5;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! That solved it!  I will keep that in mind.  Should have known.